# How to Integrate MYSql in C# Setup Project?

Tags: mysql, c#-3.0, setup-deployment

I want to install MySql and Database File while installing the Setup File,
which is developed in C#.

simply, while installing the setup file only everything needs to be installed
(MYSql,Database File)

So, please guide me on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can set Custom Launch Options to the Setup file. Add the necessary executibles in the Commit node of the setup file and those will get executed when your installation finishes.

As for installing entire MySQL, you would need to add the installation files of MySQL to the Setup project. Executing the Database Script would be simple, just call the script after MySQL installs.